# JSF PrimeFaces - Save value of selected tablecell on buttonclick

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, focus

Prerequisites:

- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

Story:

I got a datatable displaying some editable values. 
The amount of columns is dynamic.
In the same form is a button calling a save-action of my bean to save all edited data. 
The function it self is working perfectly fine

Implementation:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" scrollable="true"
    widgetVar="wigVardataTable"
    value="#{myBean.dataList}"
    var="data"
    editable="true"
    editMode="cell"
    rowKey="rowkey">        
   <p:columns var="col"
     value="#{myModel.columnList}"
     style="font-size: 12px">
     <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText
          value="#{col.header}" />
     </f:facet>
     <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText
            value="#{myModel.getValueForTableCell(data, col).value}" />
        </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText
              id="inputTxt"
              value="#{myModel.getValueForTableCell(data, col).value}"
              style="width:100%">       
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
    </p:columns>
  </p:dataTable>
```

Problem:

When pressing the save button while a table cell is being edited and didn't loose its focus yet, the new value inside the inputtext of the tablecell won't be written back into my bean and due to that won't be saved.

Question:

How can i write back the data into my backing bean, before the button action is executed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is caused by wrong ordering of ajax events. When the command button is invoked while having a cell editor open, then the ajax event of the command button is fired before the ajax event of the cell edit.

We'd thus like to swap around them. Without editing the PrimeFaces source code, you could achieve this by explicitly invoking `saveCell()` function of the `<p:dataTable>` widget when there's a cell editor open.

So, given a

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable ... widgetVar="wigVardataTable" />
    <p:commandButton ... />
</h:form>
```

you can achieve the desired behavior by adding the below `onclick` to the `<p:commandButton>`:

```
onclick="var d=PF('wigVardataTable'), c=d.jq.find('td:has(.ui-cell-editor-input:visible)'); if(c.length)d.saveCell(c)"
```

Basically, it first finds the cell with an open cell editor and then invokes `saveCell()` on it.

Another, less elegant, way is explicitly invoking `showCellEditor()` function of the `<p:dataTable>` widget without passing the expected target cell in a `try-catch` block where the exception is ignored.

```
onclick="try{PF('wigVardataTable').showCellEditor()}catch(ignore){}"
```

It will save any opened cell first and later throw an error that no new target cell was specified as argument, but that could be ignored as shown above.

---

Noted should be that this all works regardless of whether you use `<p:columns>` or `<p:column>`, and also regardless of whether you use a normal model or an overcomplicated model ;) This trick is tested on both your PrimeFaces 5.2 version and the current PrimeFaces 6.0 version.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I included your solution and so far it seems to work just fine. I'm still testing it for possible bugs but so far i couldn't find anything.

Comment: @BalusC You said the ordering of the ajax events is wrong. Does that mean this is all caused by a bug in PrimeFaces?

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works perfectly on PrimeFaces 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution inspired by BalusC answer if you have other datatables with cell editMode :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function saveAllCellsBeforeSubmit() {
        for (var widgetName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
            if (PrimeFaces.widgets[widgetName].hasOwnProperty('cfg') &amp;&amp; PrimeFaces.widgets[widgetName].cfg.hasOwnProperty('editMode') &amp;&amp; PrimeFaces.widgets[widgetName].cfg.editMode === 'cell') {
                var d = PF(widgetName);
                var c = d.jq.find('td:has(.ui-cell-editor-input:visible)');
                if (c.length) {
                    d.saveCell(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```